# Unable to set variables in a Thymeleaf template

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm using Spring Boot with some templates to help generate some dynamic emails. Unfortunately, the templating engine isn't rendering my variables.

## Backend Call

```
public String generateProblemOfTheDay(Model model) throws IOException {

    Context ctx = new Context();
    ctx.setVariable("potd", "Test Value");

    //Process the template with the proper context variables
    String html = templateEngine.process("index", ctx);
    PrintWriter pWriter = new PrintWriter(Paths.PROBLEM_OF_THE_DAY_OUTPUT, "UTF-8");
    pWriter.println(html);
    pWriter.close();
    log.info("done!");
    log.info(html);

    return html;
}
```

## Segment of my template

```html
.
.
<tr>
    <td style="font-family:'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif; font-size:15px; line-height:18px; color:#30373b;">
        <br />
        <div class="question-description">
            [[${potd}]]
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
.
.
```

I'm not sure why the template engine isn't processing the variables correctly. Is this the best way to add variables?

## What I found does work

```
<label style="font-size: 12px;padding-bottom: 1em;" th:text="${potd}">Test</label>
```

Adding something like the following does indeed work.. I've seen many people use t he standard curly bracket notation without issues and wondering what is appropriate where.

Answer (score 2):

[Inlined expressions were changed from thymeleaf 2 to 3](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/thymeleaf3migration.html#template-changes).  I'm guessing you're using thymeleaf 2, which means you need the [attribute `th:inline="text"` in order to get your expression to work](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#text-inlining).

```
<div class="question-description" th:inline="text">
    [[${potd}]]
</div>
```

If you upgrade to thymeleaf 3, those expressions will work out of the box (and it even recommends you remove `th:inline="text"`).  As for which way you should write expressions...  it is pretty much opinion based.  For the most part, I like using `th:text` directly in a tag.  If you are appending a lot of strings together, you might use the other way.  For example:

```
<span>Your answer was: [[${answer}]]</span>
```

is easier to read than

```
<span th:text="${'Your answer was:' + answer}"/>
```